# Edit yield content of an Ember block component before rendering it?

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to edit the content of the yield passed to a block component.

For example, having:

```
{{#no-foo}}foo{{/no-foo}}
```

Should output:

```
<div id="emberxxxx">bar</div>
```

Because I'd like to have something inside my component logic like this:

```
init: function() {
  this.set('yield', this.get('yield').replace('foo', 'bar'));
}
```

Is it something possible with Ember.js?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? there are other options to render a different thing inside a component for example `{{#if property}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}}` or using the component helper `{{component 'component-name'}}`. Have you considered those?

Comment: I have a `code-block` component and I'd just like to "automatically" format the code written inside it.

Comment: You can use `jQuery` for that `let content = this.$().html();`

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise this approach.  It seems like a hard-coded solution which assumes there will always be a `foo` inside the block.. in which case: "why yield a block for `foo` at all?"

Instead I would consider creating a computed property for the `foo` so you can compute/change it how you want... then yield the computed property into the block.

```
// component.hbs
{{yield computedFoo}}

// main template
{{#my-component as |computedFoo|}}
  {{computedFoo}}
{{/my-component}}
```